# How to replace a character with an specific indexOf to uppercase in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

Im trying to replace a character at a specific indexOf to uppercase.
My string is a surname plus the first letter in the last name,
looking like this: `"lovisa t"`.

I check the position with this and it gives me the right place in the string. So the second gives me 8(in this case).

```
first = texten.indexOf(" ");
second = texten.indexOf(" ", first + 1);
```

And with this I replace the first letter to uppercase.

```
var name = texten.substring(0, second);
name=name.replace(/^./, name[0].toUpperCase());
```

But how do I replace the character at "second" to uppercase?

I tested with

```
name=name.replace(/.$/, name[second].toUpperCase());
```

But it did´t work, so any input really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Wait, are you just trying to do this? `str.replace(/ [a-z]/, function (m0) { return m0.toUpperCase(); })`

Comment: Thanks, but Im not sure what this is doing?

Comment: You need to capitalize all words in sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is the second letter isn't in position `8`, but `7`.
Also this `second = texten.indexOf(" ", first + 1);` gives `-1`, not `8`, because you do not have a two spaces in your string.

If you know that the string is always in the format *surname space oneLetter* and you want to capitalize the first letter and the last letter you can simply do this:

```js
var name = 'something s';
name = name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substring(1, name.length - 1) + name[name.length -1].toUpperCase();
   
console.log(name)
```

Comment: Does the `name[...]` syntax work in Internet Explorer? I remember having problems with that (strings aren't arrays). Also, you could do `name.slice(1, -1)` instead of `.substring`.

Comment: @melpomene it works after IE6. Otherwise you can simply use `charAt()` to access the element and it should work on every browser

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that does exactly what your question title asks for: It uppercases a specific index in a string.

```js
function upperCaseAt(str, i) {
    return str.substr(0, i) + str.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + str.substr(i + 1);
}

var str = 'lovisa t';
var i = str.indexOf(' ');
console.log(upperCaseAt(str, i + 1));
```

---

However, if you want to look for specific patterns in the string, you don't need to deal with indices.

```js
var str = 'lovisa t';
console.log(str.replace(/.$/, function (m0) { return m0.toUpperCase(); }));
```

This version uses a regex to find the last character in a string and a replacement function to uppercase the match.

---

```js
var str = 'lovisa t';
console.log(str.replace(/ [a-z]/, function (m0) { return m0.toUpperCase(); }));
```

This version is similar but instead of looking for the last character, it looks for a space followed by a lowercase letter.

---

```js
var str = 'lovisa t';
console.log(str.replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function (m0) { return m0.toUpperCase(); }));
```

Finally, here we're looking for (and uppercasing) all non-space characters that are preceded by the beginning of the string or a space character; i.e. we're uppercasing the start of each (space-separated) word.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works great to :-)

Comment: You're welcome. :-) (That's what the upvote button is for, by the way: "*This answer is useful*")

Answer (score 0):

All can be done by regex replace.

`"lovisa t".replace(/(^|\s)\w/g, s=>s.toUpperCase());`

Answer (score 0):

[Alternative]
You can also do this

```
 function normalizeString(str = '') {
  if (str.length === 0) {
    return str
  }

  let lower = str.toLowerCase()
  lower[0].toUpperCase()

  if (lower.includes('_')) {
    lower = lower.replaceAll('_', ' ')
  }
  return lower[0].toUpperCase() + lower.substring(1, lower.length)
}
console.log(normalizeString('MY_NAME'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one (if it will be helpfull, better move constants to other place, due performance issues(yes, regexp creation is not fast)):

```
function normalize(str){
            var LOW_DASH = /\_/g;
            var NORMAL_TEXT_REGEXP = /([a-z])([A-Z])/g;
            if(!str)str = '';
            if(str.indexOf('_') > -1) {
                str = str.replace(LOW_DASH, ' ');
            }
            if(str.match(NORMAL_TEXT_REGEXP)) {
                str = str.replace(NORMAL_TEXT_REGEXP, '$1 $2');
            }
            if(str.indexOf(' ') > -1) {
                var p = str.split(' ');
                var out = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                    if (!p[i])continue;
                    out += p[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + p[i].substring(1) + (i !== p.length - 1 ? ' ' : '');
                }
                return out;
            } else {
                return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
            }
        }

console.log(normalize('firstLast'));//First Last
console.log(normalize('first last'));//First Last
console.log(normalize('first_last'));//First Last
```

Comment: That function does many things OP didn't ask for. The last 3 `if` statements are redundant; you don't need to check whether a regex matches before you actually do the regex match. `REMOVE_FIRST_LAST_SLASHES` is unused. `LOW_DASH` is only used once; why does it get its own variable? Why are you escaping `_` in a regex?

Comment: It cover all cases for my purposes. I can use it for form input label generation using input name. Sometimes name can be in camelCase, sometime in python_tale_case. In all of this cases I will get correct name. Of course, if you are working with kirillic, japan or chinese words, think it will work not properly.

Comment: That ... doesn't really explain anything. Why are you providing code that "cover[s] all cases for [your] purposes" instead of answering OP's question?